# How to use Backhandler in React-native

Tags: javascript

I can't exit the app When I even touch Android back button twice.
just stuck in first bottom tab.

There are four of button in the screen to go to each View.(in same class component)

Answer (score 3):

**when you call BackHandler.exitApp(); app will close but it will remain in android’s recent tab.**

```
BackHandler.exitApp();
```

Here, I will share a react-native BackHandler api example.
When you want to exit the application with clicking the back button, you should use hardwareBackPress EventListener, let’s make it clear with an example.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, BackHandler, Alert } from "react-native";

class App extends Component {

  backAction = () => {
    Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to go back?", [
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: () => null,
        style: "cancel"
      },
      { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
    ]);
    return true;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      this.backAction
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text onPress = {this.backAction} style={styles.text}>Click Back button!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to exit the app use

```
BackHandler.exitApp()
```

read the [documntation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler)

Comment: I have done with it like as below.

Comment: handleBackButton() {
        let isFocused = this.props.navigation.isFocused();
        if(isFocused){
            BackHandler.exitApp()
        } else {
            this.setState({input: null});
            this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', () => BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton))
            return true
        }
    }

Comment: but the problem is the app exited when the app should haven't.
it just exited when I touch back button inside of render View. I wanted to go just outside of View.
I add image of my screen

Answer (score 0):

```
import {BackHandler,Alert} from 'react-native';
```

```
const backAction = () => {
    Alert.alert('AppName', 'Are you sure you want to exit?', [
      {
        text: 'NO',
        onPress: () => null,
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      {text: 'YES', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()},
    ]);
    return true;
  };
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
    };
  }, []);
```